# JS - How can i compare two item in an array with nearly similar string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, compare

**Example 1:**
I have an array like this

```
let arrayA = ["task A - memberA", "task A - memberB", "task B - memberA"]
```

I want to find out if two members doing the same task, then remove the task from the after one.
**The expected output of Example 1 should be:**

```
arrayA = ["task A - memberA", "task B - memberA"]
```

**Example 2:**

```
let arrayA = [{task: "Task A", member: "MemberA"},{task: "Task A", member: "MemberB"},{task: "Task B", member: "MemberB"}]
```

**Expected result 2:**

```
arrayA = [{task: "Task A", member: "MemberA"},{task: "Task B", member: "MemberB"}]
```

Thank you,

Comment: The two answers by now (@SSM and @Vicas-Acharya) are perfect for your needs. In any case... I don't know if you could change it, but it could be better to change the elements of your array... It could be, for example, something like a more structured array of objects: `let arrayA = [{task: "Task A", member: "MemberA"},{task: "Task A", member: "MemberB"},{task: "Task B", member: "MemberB"}]`

Comment: @VFG i added another example with your array, hope we can find the answer :)

Comment: Actually, it was a suggestion because the solution would be a very different one. So I would recommend you to re-edit again the question (as it was before) in order to keep it clear with the right solution

Comment: I think i will keep these two example in case someone need the one i deleted. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @NDC8 I've updated my answer to include your second example. The code is practically identical in function, just some different variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using reduce method,

- get substring before '-' i.e task name
- check whether task name exist in pv or not
- if pv (previousValue) array of reduce function, doesn't contain the task then add that new task into it.

***hint**:

**some** method returns true or false

**includes** method return true or false

**substr** method return sub string from string i.e task name

refer MDN tutorials for more details*

```js
let arr = ["task A - memberA", "task A - memberB", "task B - memberA"]

let result = arr.reduce((pv,cv) => {
  if(!pv.some(e => e.includes(cv.substr(0, cv.indexOf('-')).trim()))) pv.push(cv)
  return pv
},[])

console.log(result)
```

**for second example just replace**
`if(!pv.some(e => e.task.includes(cv.task.trim()))) pv.push(cv)`

Comment: please explain the third line, it's not simple for me. Thank you!

Comment: @NDC8 check now

Comment: it's clear now, thank you very much Vikas!

Comment: I added another example, could you please help me solve that one?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Set` that keeps track of active tasks.

Then loop over the `tasks` array and extract the `task` by splitting the string and then if the `task` is *not* present in the `Set` then push it to the resultant array.

```js
let tasks = ["task A - memberA", "task A - memberB", "task B - memberA"];

function getUniqueTasks(tasks) {
  const activeTasks = new Set();
  const uniqueTasks = [];
  tasks.forEach((t) => {
    const [task] = t.split(" - ");
    if (!activeTasks.has(task)) {
      uniqueTasks.push(t);
      activeTasks.add(task);
    }
  });
  return uniqueTasks;
}

console.log(getUniqueTasks(tasks));
```

If you're looking for a fancy one liner, then refer to the solution below:

```js
const 
  data = ["task A - memberA", "task A - memberB", "task B - memberA"],
  filterer = (s) => (d, _i, _a, t = d.split(" - ")[0]) => !s.has(t) && s.add(t),
  result = data.filter(filterer(new Set()));

console.log(result);
```

**Relevant documentations:**

- [Set - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach)
- [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a `Set` and a function for wanted unique part of the string.

```js
const
    getTask = s => s.split(' - ', 1)[0],
    uniqueBy = fn => s => v => (w => !s.has(w) && s.add(w))(fn(v)),
    data = ["task A - memberA", "task A - memberB", "task B - memberA"],
    result = data.filter(uniqueBy(getTask)(new Set));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: A magic one-liner isn't exactly "simple" to understand to those that are just starting out with JavaScript... You should add some explanation.

Comment: This is a *really* interesting answer, inspired by this I've added another approach to my answer!

Comment: @SSM lol, don't get infected with obscurity. Readability is an important aspect of working in a team. Stick with your initial submitted answer, of which is a good answer/example.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
const arrayA = ["task A - memberA", "task A - memberB", "task B - memberA"];

function removeDuplicateTasks(tasksArray) {

    // Use set as a temporary data structure to "remember" tasks names
    const tasks = new Set();

    // Arrays have .filter() method that iterates over elements of the
    // array and uses callback function to "decide" whether given
    // element should be filtered out. Returning true from the callback
    // tells the .filter() method to let that element pass through.
    let filteredTasks = tasksArray.filter(function (task, taskIndex, tasksArr) {
        const taskName = task.split('-')[0].trim();
        if (!tasks.has(taskName)) {
            // This task name was not yet used
            tasks.add(taskName);
            // So do not throw it away but let it pass through to filteredTasks array
            return true;
        }
    });

    return filteredTasks;

}

const cleanedArrayA = removeDuplicateTasks(arrayA);
```

If I were you I'd consider using different data structure to represent member - tasks relationship.

Comment: You can leave out arguments if you don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get only the *first* entries for each specific task.

First, use `map` to transform the array in something that's a little easier to work with, an array of `[task, member]` entries.

Then, filter that array, so only those items are returned that are at the *first* position where you can find their specific task.

```js
let arrayA = ["task A - memberA", "task A - memberB", "task B - memberA"];

const assignments = arrayA.map(t => t.split(' - '));
const filtered = assignments.filter(
  ([task], i) => assignments.findIndex(
    ([t]) => t === task) === i);

console.log(filtered);
```

As for example 2, you use the *exact* same approach, aside from some variable names that changed, and you don't need to `split` any more:

```js
let arrayA = [{task: "Task A", member: "MemberA"},{task: "Task A", member: "MemberB"},{task: "Task B", member: "MemberB"}];

const filtered = arrayA.filter(
  ({task}, i) => arrayA.findIndex(
    (assignment) => assignment.task === task) === i);

console.log(filtered);
```